Since when did Movies & TV SE require registration to post questions and answers, and why was it required?
While browsing through a Meta Stack Exchange post about certain SE sites requiring users to be registered before posting questions, I noticed that Movies & TV SE was listed among those sites. (When I tested it out in a private window, I discovered that Movies & TV SE also requires registration to post answers.) Unlike the other listed sites, there's no link to the relevant meta post explaining the reason behind this decision for Movies & TV SE and when this was implemented.
Movies & TV SE was added to that meta post on August 11, 2018, by user Glorfindel, a Meta Stack Exchange moderator. After searching through the Movies & TV Meta, I couldn't find any specific discussion regarding the registration requirement. It seems that at some point on or before August 11, 2018, M&TV SE changed its policy and implemented a registration requirement for asking or answering questions.
I'm curious about the following:

When exactly did this registration requirement take effect on Movies & TV SE?
What were the reasons behind implementing this registration requirement?
Who implemented this policy change on behalf of the Movies & TV SE community?

I'm interested in understanding the rationale behind this decision and the timeline of its implementation. If anyone from the moderation team could shed some light on this matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

As a moderator I have no idea as to the onboarding experience of new users or when (if ever) that changed. I was registered (originally on Stackoverflow) prior to the site coming into existence and do not recall any 'policy change' being advertised.

Its probably fairly easy to guess the rationale here - M&TV is quite likely to suffer from drive-by posts because of the very general interests being discussed here.  A registration process is a brake on 'me too' posts and poor quality content.

@iandotkelly You're probably right about the rationale behind it, but I'm still unsure since there's no documented discussion about it that I could find. As a moderator, do you have a way to check if there are any details about when and why this was implemented? Most of the other sites listed in that meta post had meta discussions or chat conversations about implementing the registration requirement and explaining the reasons behind it. Movies & TV SE seems to lack that kind of documented information, which is why I asked about it.

Also, it's worth noting that Science Fiction & Fantasy SE, a site with a significant topic overlap with (and much higher post activity than) Movies & TV SE, doesn't require registration for posting.

I thought it was actually much longer ago and done by Shog9 during some terrible spam period and just never revoked.

According to our data the setting was turned on July 9th, 2017 by a former member of the Community Management Team to help mitigate a troll/spam wave that was occurring at the time and never turned off.
There are times that Community Managers, especially the Trust & Safety team, will utilize this setting during periods of excessive disruption as an abuse prevention tool without community consensus. However, we do communicate with moderators before implementing this change. This is what happened in this instance, as moderators were aware of the change at the time.
